# Set suspend VM by default when creating breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I make Eclipse create all new breakpoints with "suspend VM" selected (i.e. suspend all threads), instead of just "suspend thread"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Preferences, navigate to **Java** > **Debug** and change the value of "**Default suspend policy for new breakpoints**."